# How to log large payloads ( request and response ) from dependent service for troubleshooting?

Tags: logging, json.net, asp.net-web-api2

I am hosting a service which will call external dependent service to complete one business workflow and there were some situations where we have to work with external team for production issues and have to share request we sent and response payload we got to confirm that issue was at their end . Issue is sometimes when we are getting peak load we are getting out of memory exceptions at this serialization statement

we have logged all request and response using logger which will first serialize the business entity into JSON using newton json.net and then 
log into application insights

_logger.WriteEvent("External Data Response: Available products are :: " + Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(SKUS), TraceEventType.Information,

As we are getting out of memory exceptions , i was thinking for best way to log these large request and response payloads in to some external source like table storage etc but for this again we have to serialize in to json and log so issue still will be there , what is best way to solve this issue ? Any pointers will be highly helpful

Comment: Why not just use local files? You can read the html stream is reasonable size chunks and write it out in those chunks. That will be a minor memory footprint.  Make the file name the session and time stamp. I assume that this is temporary and would be turned off as soon as you know what is going on.

Comment: Actually these are not temporary and we want to keep on logging every request and response so to know what happen in production on doing root cause analysis